# Keep plymouth splash screen visible during app initialization

Tags: raspberry-pi, plymouth

On my raspberry, I have enabled [plymouth](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/plymouth) splash screen and I have a custom systemd service that starts an app at boot.

My problem is that the initialization of the app takes some time and currently plymouth splash disappears long before the app is ready, resulting in a long black screen.

What would be the proper way to keep plymouth splash visible during app initialization ?